# How to persist data form page to page for apple devices - Google tag manager

Tags: ios, cookies, local-storage, google-tag-manager

I am having a problem tracking conversions on Apple devices. This is the simplified scenario:

1. After login. User lands on page 1, behind the scenes, we push-piece of information into local storage specifying the original subscription date.
2. A GTM variable is created to hold this value, and when the conversion happens we push the variable value (subscription date) into the custom GA dimension ( to understand conversion velocity ).

This works fine on other devices except on Apple (data is missing). Is there any other way to persist piece of data from page to page on apple devices besides cookies and (or) local storage?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be best to debug the issue properly. Actually reproduce the misbehavior of apple devices. And narrow down the problem. Also, figure out if this behavior depends on a device or on Safari. It's likely that it's about the browser rather than device.

It may be connected to nuances of local/session storage management in Safari. I would suggest trying a different kind of client-side storage.

It may also be connected to Apple's old PR stunt with their ITP efforts: https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/

We normally solve this issue with a backend mirror that resets cookies that we need to be persistent. That way, cookies become first-party and the ITP limitations are relaxed. There's nuance to this approach, however. For example, having it universally resetting any cookie may be a security issue, so cookie names and their values should be validated on that backend mirror.

If you have to go this far to fix the issue, you may as well consider starting using the server-side GTM container altogether.